# For loop: process files in different folders UNIX

Tags: file, loops, terminal, directory, fastq

I have tried to find an answer to my question looking at similar topics but didn't succeed. Maybe I have overlooked. Any help is appreciated!

So, I have hundreds of folders in my current directory named from folder1000 to folder1500. In each folder, I have one .fastq file with a different name (Lib1.fastq, Lib2.fastq, etc). I want to proceed each of these files in one loop command by running a shell script.

Here is my shell script (script.sh) for one file (it creates outputs which further proceeded) which I run in my Terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
bowtie --threads 4 -v 2 -m 10 -a genome Lib1.fastq --sam > Lib1.sam
samtools view -h -o Lib1.sam Lib1.bam
sort -k 3,3 -k 4,4n Lib1.sam > Lib1.sam.sorted
# ...etc
```

Here is the loop I am trying to make as well in a shell script (here I have started only with a simple checking "head" command, and only with 5 first folders) which I run from my current directory where all folders are located:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./folder{1000..1005}
do
head -10 *.fastq
done
```

But as a result I get:

```
head: *.fastq: No such file or directory
head: *.fastq: No such file or directory
head: *.fastq: No such file or directory
head: *.fastq: No such file or directory
head: *.fastq: No such file or directory
```

So, even a simple checking command does not work for me in a loop. Somehow I can not see the file. But if I run the command directly in one of the folders:

```
MacBook-Air-Maxim:folder1000 maxim$ head -10 *.fastq
```

then I get the correct result (the first 10 lines of the file displayed).

Could anyone suggest the way to process all files in the most convenient way?

Thanks a lot and very sorry, I am just learning.

Comment: You might want to use seq one day: `for i in $(seq 1000 1500); do echo $i; done`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are traversing through the folders using the variable `$file`, but you are not using this variable in the loop body. Just use it:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./folder{1000..1005}
do
    head -10 $file/*.fastq
done
```

There are other issues in the overall problem, but this is the answer to the point that is stopping you. Let's tackle the problems one by one :-)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot @Poshi ! This works! You are right, there is a huge mass of the things which still has to be done.

So, funny thing. It runs "head" command, but when I use the next ones right after head command it says that it can no find the file - "head: ./folder1000/*.fastq: No such file or directory
stat: No such file or directory"

Comment: I am curious, maybe the whole strategy is not correct and there is a better way to organize it... Because that way I have to import all other supportive files in each folder to actually make the code run

Comment: I am not sure what actually is happening. It seems for me that the file is under restricted access or smth. It shows the number of aligned reads, and then says that it can not find it. One of the error messages as well is: "Warning: Could not open read file "./folder1000/*.fastq" for reading; skipping..."

Comment: `No such file` is quite different from `Could not open file for reading`. They are different problems. I would reccomend you to take some introductory course on Linux basics, command line and file systems.